# Is this endgame winnable (for White)?

Tags: endgame, evaluation, bishop-endgame

I ran into this position during a game against a computer, but I'm not sure if its winnable (I'm, White). Also, any comments on my play/computer's play would be highly appreciated.

I'm not sure how to use this site's chess diagrams, so I'll just post the PGN file here:

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 e6 2. d3 d5 3. exd5 exd5 4. c3 Bd6 5. g3 Ne7 6. Bg2 O-O 7. Nf3 Re8 8. O-O Nbc6 9. Be3 Nf5 10. Re1 Nxe3 11. Rxe3 Rxe3 12. fxe3 Qe7 13. Qe2 Bg4 14. Nbd2 Re8 15. e4 f5 16. Re1 fxe4 17. dxe4 Ne5 18. Qe3 Bxf3 19. Nxf3 Nxf3+ 20. Qxf3 c6 21. a3 Qe6 22. b4 Kh8 23. Qd3 Bc7 24. Kh1 Kg8 25. Qd4 Bb6 26. Qd3 Bc7 27. a4 b6 28. Qd4 Qe5 29. Kg1 Qe6 30. Qd2 Qe5 31. Re3 Re6 32. Qf2 Re8 33. Kh1 Qe6 34. Qf3 Kh8 35. h3 Kg8 36. Kh2 c5 37. Qg4 Qe5 38. Qd7 Rd8 39. Qf5 Qxf5 40. exf5 cxb4 41. cxb4 Kf7 42. Rd3 d4 43. Be4 Be5 44. Kg2 Kf6 45. g4 Rc8 46. Kf3 Rc4 47. Bd5 Rc1 48. Bg8 h5 49. Bb3 Rf1+ 50. Kg2 Rf4 51. Bd1 a6 52. b5 axb5 53. axb5 Re4 54. Ra3 Re1 55. Rd3 Re4 56. Ra3 Re1 57. Rd3 hxg4 58. hxg4 Re4 59. Kf3 Rf4+ 60. Kg2 Ke7 61. Kh3 Rf2 62. Kh4 Kf6 63. Rf3 Rxf3 64. Bxf3 d3 *
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not sure how to use this site's chess diagrams

First off, to learn how to make chess diagrams here **read carefully** [answers to this post](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279/tool-used-to-create-chess-analysis-interactive-diagrams-in-many-chess-stack-exch).

As for your question, I will give you brief comments about the game first, and then analyze the endgame.

> Also, any comments on my play/computer's play would be highly appreciated.

Since SO hasn't added written commentaries to follow a move, I will refer to the move, and then comments will follow.

If you have further questions leave a comment.

Best regards.

Let us start:

Your opening play was not precise, but you still had a playable position until `15.e4`. After that move Black had a small advantage and an initiative. I do not play `1.e4`, nor do I play the *French defense*. Even if I did, I would advise you to prepare your openings well by consulting an opening book. That should remedy the mistakes you made in your game.

Although Black was better, you still could count on a draw. `21.a3` seems desperate-it looks like you had no idea what to do, and it is a pointless move. You have no advantage at the queenside so there is no reason to start action there. This would also be slow plan and would weaken you more than helping you. At this moment it was crucial to somehow break the pin. One idea would be `Rd1` after `b4`-something like this:

```
[White "namehere"]
[Black "Computer player"]
[fen "4r1k1/pp2q1pp/2pb4/3p4/4P3/2P2QP1/PP4BP/4R1K1 w - - 0 1"]

1.b4 a6 2.Rd1! dxe4 3.Qxe4! Qxe4 4.Bxe4 Rxe4 5.Rxd6
```

with some chances to draw.

At move `23.` you had a chance to execute my combination and get back into the game. At the end of the combination the opponent's king would be threatened by mate, so you could get a slight advantage there.
After missing this chance, you had to struggle for a draw-I would try to reorganize my pieces like this:

```
[Title "Suggestion for piece placement"]
[fen "4r1k1/pp2q1pp/2pb4/3p4/4P3/2P2BP1/PP2R1KP/4Q3 w - - 0 1"]
```

so I can achieve `exd5` and equalize.

The rest of the game the computer played pathetically and squandered the advantage.

> Is this endgame winnable(for White)?

As for the endgame, it is a draw-Black plays `Bf4` and enforces blockade on the dark squares after which White has nothing. It will look something like this:

```
[Title "Endgame analysis"]
[fen "8/6p1/1p3k2/1P2bP2/6PK/3p1B2/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

1.Be4 d2 2.g5+ Ke7 3.Bc2 Bf4 4.Kh5 Kf8 5.Kg6 Be5 6.f6 gxf6 7.gxf6 Bd4 8.f7 Bc3=
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments, it's really helpful. The reasons why I love SE!

Comment: I'm not sure why black would play a6 in response to b4. Also, could I have some more advice on how to play a good opening?

Comment: @namehere: `a6` is weak, but was "played" just so I can show you how to perform a combination. The true chance to play `Rd1!` came later, as I have pointed out. As for openings, I need more information to help you. A separate question could help me-especially if you provide more specific details of what you need help with. Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, white can't win. Let white do any move except g5+ (Kh5, for example)
65... g5 66. fxg6 Kg7 Now black bishop will move on squares c5 and g1 and white can't do any progress because pawns are blocked.

Moreover, I like black's position more,

Comment: May I also receive some advice on my play? Thanks.